# "Select" statement to pick up records

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL select statement help needed

```
ClientId    BenefitType
1000        1
1001        1
1001        2
1003        2
1003        3
1004        1
1004        3
```

I want select only those ClientsIds which have `BenefitType = 1` but no other `BenefitType` since `ClientId` isn't a unique id in this table and can have multiple rows. So in the above example, the answer should be 1000.

There are four different types benefits. A client can have any combination of them. I am trying to select only those clients which have only **one** specific type of benefit. Let's say that benefit types are 1, 2, 3, 4. I want to select clients with `BenefitType=2` who NOT have any other benefit i.e `1`, `3`, `4`.

I am using Oracle and the table has around 6 million records.  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try using WHERE clause?

Comment: I tried following

Comment: How is the only answer = 1000 when 1001 and 1004 also have BenefitType = 1 ?

Comment: @PaulKaram Asking the real question :)

Comment: I tried following   select ClientId ,BenefitType from tableA where BenefitType = 1 and not exists (select ClientId from tableA where BenefitType  in (2,3) ; this picks up 1000 , 1001 and 1004, which is wrong

Comment: @matb Please explain how is this wrong, and please state which DBMS are you using. And clarify your question. Because this is not wrong.

Comment: I think my example did not explain the scenario clearly. I will try again, There are four different types benefits. A client can have any combination of them. I am trying to select only those clients which have only ONE specific type benefit. let say if benefits type are 1, 2, 3, 4. I want to select client with BenefitType 2, same client should NOT have any other benefit i.e 1, 3, 4. I am using Oracle and table has arround 6 million records

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  Which dbms????  What have you tried????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarifying your question, here's how to do it:

```
select * 
from tableA
where BenefitType = 1
and ClientId not in (select ClientId 
                     from tableA 
                     where BenefitType != 1)
```

Output:

```
ClientId | BenefitType
1000     | 1
```

You can check it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4657/2

Comment: This will produce the right answer, the problem is how it will perform against six million records.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL

```
SELECT ClientId
FROM tablename
WHERE BenefitType = 1
LIMIT 1;
```

In Oracle

```
SELECT ClientId
FROM tablename
WHERE BenefitType = 1
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Additionally, Add Below Line To Get Smallest ID

```
ORDER BY ClientId ASC;
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the question (to be fair the question is not well-phrased).

Comment: Thats True I Just Thought May Be It Could Be Of Some Help To Some One Else

Comment: @ShreyGupta True, but this isn't how SO works. You just don't leave "stuff" here and there because it "could" help someone. It's merely a Q&A, answers should only involve answering the questions itself. Only if it's necessary, you can leave more comments in your answer for more information.

Comment: Sorry For That @PaulKaram Will Keep It In Mind